# Variable substitution does not work in Web.Config section

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have this custom section in Web.config

```
<serviceWorker PriorityCronExp="__serviceWorker_PriorityCronExp__" ScheduledCronExp="__serviceWorker_ScheduledCronExp__" />
```

I want to replace the variables in my release, I have configured the variables and checked "XML Variable subsitution", but my release is not detecting the variables the vars are not replaced.
Other variables have been replaced correctly (defined in appSettings).
Is there a way to get the variables replaced without having to modify my Web.Config?

P.S. I am targeting .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: Which task are you using? Do you have one for .json and another for .config?

Comment: I am using Azure App Service Deploy Task. I don't have json file I am working in .Net Framework 4.8

Comment: Hi Cristiano; can you paste in the YAML of the task which you're expecting to do with variable substitution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see the whole structure of your Web.config, But I can probably tell what happened on your side.

The feature 'XML variable substitution' only works for applicationSettings, appSettings, connectionStrings, and configSections. Only these will work.

It is clearly clarify here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-variable-substitution

> This feature enables you to modify configuration settings in
> configuration files (*.config files) inside web packages and XML
> parameters files (parameters.xml). In this way, the same package can
> be configured based on the environment to which it will be deployed.
>
> Variable substitution takes effect only on the applicationSettings,
> appSettings, connectionStrings, and configSections elements of
> configuration files. If you are looking to substitute values outside
> of these elements you can use a (parameters.xml) file, however you
> will need to use a 3rd party pipeline task to handle the variable
> substitution.

This is how it design.

If I misunderstand something, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thansk, however this doesn't answer my question, which is if there is a way to make the variables replacement work with my web.config structure.

Comment: @CristianoSchiaffella Original DevOps features can't achieve your requirements, I think modify the Web.config via code is inevitable. Use regular expression to find the value and change it should be a good choice. Of course, edit the value directly is also a way.

Comment: Ok, my solution was to edit my web.config. I am sorry that it cannot be done otherwise. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the variables replaced without having to modify my Web.Config?

Yes. I suggest that you can add RegEx Match & Replace task from [RegEx Match & Replace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kasunkodagoda.regex-match-replace) to your Pipeline to modify the web.config file.

This task will use regular expressions to match fields in the file.

```
steps:
- task: RegExMatchReplace@2
  displayName: 'RegEx Match & Replace'
  inputs:
    PathToFile: web.config
    RegEx: 'PriorityCronExp="(?:[^\\"]|\\\\|\\")*" ScheduledCronExp="(?:[^\\"]|\\\\|\\")*"'
    ValueToReplace: 'PriorityCronExp="$(variabename1)" ScheduledCronExp="$(variablename2)"'
```

Then the value will update.

You can use this site to convert the regular expressions : [Regex Generator](https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/?sampleText=2020-03-12T13%3A34%3A56.123Z%20INFO%20%20%5Borg.example.Class%5D%3A%20This%20is%20a%20%23simple%20%23logline%20containing%20a%20%27value%27.&flags=i&onlyPatterns=false&matchWholeLine=false&selection=)

Comment: This solution may work but I don't like having to change my task script every time the web.config file is changed.